Android OnCreate not accepting null savedInstanceState in .Net Maui
In my .Net Maui application, I have to override the basic Android OnCreate method as follows :
protected override void OnCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    base.OnCreate(savedInstanceState);

    ThemeChanged(AppCore.Instance.CurrentThemeDark());

    MauiUtils.AndroidUtils.Permissions.GetInstance(this).GetPermissions(PermissionsGroupLocation);
}

My issue being, sometimes (but I actually have no clue of when or why) when I start my app to debug it using the Visual Studio emulator, I end up having an exception in this method : base.OnCreate(savedInstanceState) raises **System.NullReferenceException:** 'Object reference not set to an instance of an object.'.
I can confirm with a breakpoint that savedInstance is actually null, however the base OnCreate method accepts a Bundle? as parameter, and my method in itself doesn't use the savedInstance at all.
The only way I found to fix this is to completely reset the emulator, and I suppose it's an emulator-related issue, but wanted to ask in case I was actually missing something.

Can you make sure what's null? And did you try to move the two lines code into other method, such as App's constructor?

savedInstanceState is null, and I tried commenting out these two lines, still end up with this error

How can we reproduce this problem? Could you please post the steps of reproducing this problem?
